# modifying the AssemblyInfo.cs file not working. Getting the message "this file has been modified outside the source editor"

Tags: build

I updated the assemlyversion in the assemblyinfo.cs file. But when I try to build it it changes are reverted automatically.Visual studio shows a message that "this file has been modified outside the source editor. Do you want to reload it?" . Why is this happening ? Does anyone have an idea about it? I have tried excluding and then including the file again . But it did not help.

Comment: How are you updating the AssemblyVersion?

Comment: I am updating [assembly: AssemblyVersion("7.1.5.8")] section in assemblyinfo.cs file.

Comment: So you're not using a command line tool to change the version? Do you have any build events that could be modifying the file?

Comment: Sounds to me it is actually working.  Do make sure to click YES.  Or edit the file yourself instead of letting some prebuild event modify the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried closing the file in visual studio? You'll get this warning whenever a file is modified by something other than visual studio while the file is open.